# RJ45 connector on breadboard

Tags: breadboard, rj45

For my project which for the next (many) months I want to make it on a breadboard.

I ordered RJ45 connectors, but these do not fit on a breadboard. What would be a good way (or is there a way) to connect these on a breadboard?

Of course I can solder 8 wires but than still the connector is hanging loose. 
Maybe there is a (not necessarily electric solution) how to keep these connectors in place somehow, but I don't have experience in it.

[image]

Comment: Is the pitch matching? Then cut these plastic pins. And yes, you an always just hot-glue it to the board. Or use this (or similar) breakout: https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/BOB-00716/1568-1097-ND/5318739?WT.mc_id=IQ_7604_G_pla5318739&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1&mkwid=sGiHrz3ur&pcrid=102742927745&pkw=&pmt=&pdv=c&gclid=Cj0KCQjwgIPOBRDnARIsAHA1X3QYU0ib41bq3lfx3vORNX4X20tKxXENUKET8cDphGA0eXeb0E1wtucaAnrGEALw_wcB

Comment: First you need to consider *why* you are using an RJ45 and if that belongs on a breadboard.  Occasionally these are used for custom signalling systems, but that's not a particularly good idea.  If using it for Ethernet you probably want to put the magnetics on the custom part as well, so you do not have to breadboard those.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The pitch is not fitting to a breadboard (but I ordered through this question a few adapter boards

Comment: @Chris Stratton ... I discussed this in another question ... I need about 1-2 meters, I want a 'decent' connection (not one that easily can be taken out), yet not so big (not like DB9). And I'm not using it for Ethernet, but for CAN signals. Breadboarding is only for development (which can take a half year or so, since it's a 'hobby free time project'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen ready-made "breakout boards" being sold for RJ45 connectors (RJ45 connector + header pins on 0.1" pitch already fitted to PCB). Search the usual places.

Alternatively, use hot glue to mount the RJ45 socket on a small piece of normal 0.1" "perf board" prototype PCB yourself (for mechanical stability). Then solder wires between the RJ45 pins and header pins which you have mounted in the "perf board".

Comment: That sounds like a good idea (I cannot find those, except one for 6 euro). But perfboard sounds good (I don't have it yet, but I need to order those anyway if I continue my project).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - I don't know why you are seeing prices of 6 Euros for a breakout board. :-( On the UK Ebay site, I see many sellers for around £1, or a little more, after doing a search for - breakout rj45 - who appear to ship to Europe for free. Although not useful for you in mainland Europe (due to shipping costs) there are also UK sellers who have them (although not in stock right now) e.g. https://www.proto-pic.co.uk/breakout-board-for-rj45.html - again, £1 + VAT + very reasonable UK shipping. Of course any breakouts would be risky for Ethernet over the RJ45. I assume that doesn't apply.

Comment: I just found 5 China ones on Ebay for $2,46, so that's a good price. Same like the one in the RJ45 breakout pic below. And I want to use it for a CAN bus connection.

Comment: It seems the search function for AliExpress does not work well ... while looking further in the lists I found ones for E 0,47 :-).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - Glad you found something suitable - yes, they get cheaper in quantity. At CAN bus speeds, I would minimise the lengths of the jumper wires joining the breakout to the CAN transceiver, and keep them twisted. Good luck!

Comment: I will not use the breakout board probably for the eventual 'system'... the breakout is just for during development. I got the tip to use network (UTP5) cables ... therefore the RJ45 connectors. The length of the cable will be around 2 meters maximum anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Several ways:

- Make a small PCB which holds the connector and also 0.1"-aligned pins, or buy one ([example, not the same footprint as your connector](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/716)).
- Solder wires on, terminate the other ends of the wires with “dupont” 0.1" header pins, glue/tape them together.
- Put your breadboard on a larger board (that's what the double-sided tape it comes with is for) and fasten the RJ45 connector to it however you like.

Comment: Good ideas .... I like that RJ45 breadboard adapter ... too bad it costs 4 euro to send ... I also should get dupont header pins for your second solution.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers If it's only a one-off project and you're not especially broke, I'd just pay it. If you have a choice between saving a few euros and having an important part, you need the important part...

Answer (score 3):

Do a quick search for "RJ45 breadboard" and lots of options come up; something like this:

[image: RJ45 Breakout]

Comment: I tried AliExpress but without any results... I see something on Ebay (but they cost 6 euro including shipping) although it has the RJ45 connector already on it: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/RJ45-Ethernet-Connector-Breakout-Board-Dual-Row-0-1-Header-Breadboard-Friendly-/182477377939?hash=item2a7c7fd193:g:QPMAAOSwuxFYu8ia   ... guess I need to look to the interesting pic you have (exactly what I need)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers this specific one is from SparkFun, although I'm sure they are available elsewhere also.

Comment: Yes, I found them also at AliExpress, however, somehow the results were not shown initially the way I wanted. But I ordered 2 (47 cents per piece). Thank you (this is exactly I need). Also I can improve my soldering skills a bit when adding the pin headers :-)